# Bash: command not found / not a valid object name:'master'

Tags: bash, git

I am really struggling with my shell.

All of the sudden it looks like this and any command prompts the following:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to put some `git` information in your prompt, but you've spelled the command name wrong.  Can you `echo $PS1`?

Comment: $ echo $PS1 returns the following:

\e[0;35m-&gt;&gt; \e[1;34m\W\e[0;32m$(parse_git_branch)\e[0;37m $
-bash: gt: command not found
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first check if the commands are in your `PATH`?

And if they're not try this:
`export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

seems like a similar issue to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167454/basic-commands-in-unix-not-working-i-e-bash-ls-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: but it seems, that all commands like -ls or -cd, -top etc. are working properly. I just cannot open psql postgres and every command prompts the stated errors

Answer (score 0):

## solved

I went to my bash_profil and deleted the git stuff.
Surely not the elegant solution but it works for now.
What exactly happened to my git, I ll see that later

thx guys